# Excluindo item de uma lista (dicionário) - Python

Tags: python

Eu possuo um dicionário chamado `alunos`, que funciona relacionando o nome de um aluno e uma lista de notas, por exemplo:

```
alunos = {'Fulano': [2, 4, 10, 5.5]}
```

Preciso excluir o primeiro valor dessa lista, tendo o nome do aluno como parâmetro mas não consigo fazer essa operação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para remover o primeiro elemento de uma lista, utilize o método `remove` passando o primeiro valor da lista como parâmetro.

```py
alunos = {'Fulano': [2, 4, 10, 5.5]}
alunos['Fulano'].remove(alunos['Fulano'][0])
print(alunos['Fulano'])
```

Output:

```py
[4, 10, 5.5]
```

`alunos['Fulano']` refere-se à lista de notas do nome do aluno, `alunos['Fulano'][0]` refere-se ao primeiro valor da lista.

Comment: Outra opção (que acho até mais simples) é  `alunos['Fulano'].pop(0)`

Comment: Também pode usar `del alunos['Fulano'][0]`